# css3 rotation with nth-child doesnt work as expected

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-selectors

1. I have a guestbook.
2. I would like to rotate every 1st post(-0.7deg) and every 2nd .post(0.7deg)
3. The .chain has only a background-image.
4. When there's no .chain div, it works with .post:nth-child(2n+1)
5. With this css i can only rotate all in the same direction.
6. I tried everything, but it doesn't work. Please help me.

[image]

The html:

```
<form></form>    
<div class="chain"></div>
<article class="post">
   <h3>Peter Parker</h3>
   <span class="time">2014.03.17 18:53</span>
   <span class="message">This is a nice page.</span>
</article>
<div class="chain"></div>
<article class="post">
   <h3>John Smith</h3>
   <span class="time">2014.03.17 18:00</span>
   <span class="message">Hi! My name is John</span>
</article>
...
```

The css:

```
.post{
    border: 30px solid transparent;
    border-image:url("stb/border.png") 45 45 45 45 repeat stretch;
    border-width:20px 20px 20px 20px;
    -moz-border-image:url("stb/border.png") 45 45 45 45 repeat stretch;
    -webkit-border-image:url("stb/border.png") 45 45 45 45 repeat stretch;
    border-image-outset: 10px;
    background-color:#fffcd6;
    text-align:center;  
}
.chain{
    margin:0 auto;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    min-width:30px;
    min-height:30px;
    background: url('stb/lanc.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center center;
}
.post:nth-child(4n+3) .post:nth-child(4n+4){
    -ms-transform:rotate(0.7deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0.7deg);
    transform:rotate(0.7deg);
}
.post:nth-child(4n+1) .post:nth-child(4n+2){
    -ms-transform:rotate(-0.7deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-0.7deg);
    transform:rotate(-0.7deg);
}
```

I tried this one too:

```
.chain:nth-child(odd) .vk:nth-child(odd){
    -ms-transform:rotate(0.7deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0.7deg);
    transform:rotate(0.7deg);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not with the degrees. 0.7 works fine, if it works. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need commas between the selectors. You were using the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators).

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VhrHV/)

```
.post:nth-child(4n+3), .post:nth-child(4n+4){
/*                   ^                      */
    -ms-transform:rotate(0.7deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0.7deg);
    transform:rotate(0.7deg);
}
.post:nth-child(4n+1), .post:nth-child(4n+2){
/*                   ^                      */
    -ms-transform:rotate(-0.7deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-0.7deg);
    transform:rotate(-0.7deg);
}
```

You could probably simplify this and use `:nth-child(even)`/`nth-child(odd)`. This, however, wouldn't work because of the `<div class="chain"></div>` elements. You could therefore replace them with pseudo elements (`:before`/`:after`) like this:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/trn8k/)

```
.post:nth-child(even) {
    -ms-transform:rotate(2deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);
    transform:rotate(2deg);
}
.post:nth-child(odd) {
    -ms-transform:rotate(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-2deg);
    transform:rotate(-2deg);
}
.post {
    /* other styling.. */
    position:relative;
}
.post:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: url('//placehold.it/10x200');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center center;
    left: 50%;
    top: 100%;
    margin-left: -15px; /* Half the width.. */
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the comma disappeared after the 421593. change in the css. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well spotted. Also, in the first demo, 4n+1 and 4n+3 are useless. And, to make it better looking in webkit and FF, add a perspective function to the transform  http://jsfiddle.net/VhrHV/1/

Comment: The :after thing doesn't work here, because the posts don't have the same height. http://users.atw.hu/darksoul90/egyeb/atw2.png

Comment: @darksoul90 It works here with differing heights. http://jsfiddle.net/rdfWL/ As for an alternative solution, you could make the chains longer so that they extend beyond the space.. then you would just hide the excess with a negative `z-index`.. as for another solution, you could use one single element that extends the height of the entire background..